# Solve $X''(t) + f(g(t)) X(t) = 0$ using the solutions of $X''(t) + f(t)X(t) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the ODE
$$X''(t) + f(g(t)) X(t) = 0$$
And I know the solutions of
$$X''(t) + f(t) X(t) =0$$
Is there a way I can find the solutions of the first ODE using the second? I think I can't in general, they seem to be completely different problems even though the equations are similar. But for $g(t) = t$, the solutions are the same, obviously. Or if $g(t) = -t$, then $\varphi(-t)$ is a solution for the first if $\varphi(t)$ is a solution for the second. So its possible in some cases. I would like to know if it is possible to do the same for other $g$.

I notice if $F(r,s) = A(r)B(s)$, where $A$ is a solution to the first ODE and $B$ is a solution to the second, then $F_{rr}(t,g(t)) = F_{ss}(t,g(t))$. I don't know if this helps. Any ideas/hints/references are welcome (I am a newbie in differential equations).

Thanks